# French locale translated characters display as question mark/wrong

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

Am having this error in php language translation based on country using date() function .

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
setlocale( LC_TIME,'fr_FR', 'fr_FR.utf8', 'fr_FR.UTF8', 'French');
```

and am using strftime

```
echo strftime('%d.%m.%Y');
```

am getting that question mark symbol while in live. how to fix that, thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a problem with charsets.

Comment: Something to do with localization, since you can't display an E acute accent. Your code is fine.

Comment: First comment on the documentation : `If strange characters are returned use utf8_encode(strftime()) for UTF-8 characters`

Comment: am using charset also <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: @Debflav Most comments on the PHP manual are worthless, especially when they pertain to encodings. `utf8_encode` is a bandaid, not a proper fix. It should be your last resort to patch every invocation of `strftime` with it. Fixing your locales should be the primary goal.

Comment: thanks Debflav, My error fixed

Comment: @deceze : To my mind it can solve "temporarily" the problem. And I'm not agreed, some comment on the manual can help to identify where does a problem, even if we should keep a critical aspect. Edit: And btw I don't put it as an answer because I knew it wasn't the best solution.

Comment: @Debflav Yes, and now the OP is using `utf8_encode` everywhere instead of understanding and fixing his locale installation once and for all. Great.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `setlocale` will use the first locale from your given list that it can find. Most likely the `fr_FR` locale matches first and is not using UTF-8, and/or you do not have the UTF-8 variants of that locale installed at all and/or you got their names wrong. Check your installed locales with `locale -a` (CLI command) and prioritise the UTF-8 versions before generic versions like `fr_FR`.

My locales:

```
$ locale -a | grep fr_FR
fr_FR
fr_FR.ISO8859-1
fr_FR.ISO8859-15
fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Therefore:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.UTF-8', 'fr_FR', 'French');
```

To demonstrate the difference it makes:

```
$ php -r 'setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR.ISO8859-1"); echo strftime("%A %B");'
Vendredi f?vrier

$ php -r 'setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR.UTF-8"); echo strftime("%A %B");'
Vendredi février
```

Comment: for spanish setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8', 'es_ES', 'Spanish');